# jQuery auto upload file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the file input will automatic upload my image without enter any submit button.

```
<form action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="47" />
  <input type="file" name="upload" />
</form>
```

Let me know the trick with jQuery

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can submit the form on the file input's onchange event, like this:

```
$("input[name=upload]").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: wonderful jquery ;) if possible how do I display loading bar while uploading until it done?

Comment: Got it ;) `$("#upload").change(function(){$(this).closest("form").submit();$('#loader').show();$(this).hide();});`

Answer (score 7):

With more recent versions you can also just set the autoUpload option to true:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({ autoUpload: true });
```

Comment: In the file js/main.js