# Can I auto-submit a file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to facilitate a file upload without a submit button. I've managed to hide the file upload button but I'm not sure whether it is possible to hide the submit button and also auto-submit the form when the file is added to the form. Can it be done?

My code is

```
  <form id="inputForm" role="form" class="marg-left" action="/admin/import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input id="upload" name="file" type="file"/><a href="" id="upload_link"><div class="navigation-button">
            <div class="navigation-header">Import</div>
            <div class="navigation-desc">Import from tab-separated files on disk </div>
        </div>   </a>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

CSS

```
#upload{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen for the `change` event.

```
$("#upload:hidden").on('change', function(){
    $('#inputForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek19/qx7Rn/)**

Comment: like the new approach of adding code using jfiddler

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done.Try this:

```
    <input id="upload" name="file" type="file" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("#upload_link").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upload:hidden").trigger('click');
    });
    $("#upload:hidden").on('change', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //submit form
        $('#inputForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can submit the form using following JQuery:

```
$('inputForm').submit()
```

the full answer can be found here : [jQuery auto upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476546/jquery-auto-upload-file)